# Добавить индекс элемента массива

Tags: jquery

```
var sliderLength = $(".quote-wrapp").length;
var pointLength = $(".point").length;

var point = $(".point");
var slide = $(".quote-wrapp");

var activePoint = $(".active");
var activeSlide = $(".active-slide");

var slideNumber;

console.log("sliderLength " + sliderLength);
console.log("pointLength " + pointLength);


point.click(function()
{
point.removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

slideNumber = $(this).index();

console.log("slideNumber " + slideNumber);

slide.removeClass("active-slide");
slide[slideNumber].addClass("active-slide");

});
```

мне пишет, что slide[slideNumber].addClass is not a function, я так понимаю я как-то не правильно обратился к массиву и оно его не находит, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
$(slide[slideNumber]).addClass("active-slide");
```

или

```
slide.eq(slideNumber).addClass("active-slide");
```

Answer (score 0):

В переменной `slide` хранится `jQuery` объект, а не массив, поэтому у этой переменной есть метод `.addClass` и другие.

При обращении по индексу, например `slide[slideNumber]` - результатом будет обычный `HTMLElement`, у которого нет методов `jQuery`, поэтому нужно обернуть его в `jQuery`, например передав его в функцию `$`

```
$(slide[slideNumber]).addClass("active-slide");
```

Чтобы получить конкретный элемент из коллекции `jQuery` можно воспользоваться методом [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
slide.eq(slideNumber).addClass("active-slide");
```

Comment: Вы полностью скопировали ответ @Igor. Нда уж.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, не, смотри внимательнее - не скопировал